# Drools Knapsack Optaplanner

Tags: drools, knapsack-problem, optaplanner

I try to solve the Knapsack-Problem with the Optaplanner by using drools. Did someone this before? This refers to the example by optaplanner.

Thanks for your help

I have implemented these rules as follows:

`rule "weigth" 
dialect "java"
when

$knapsack : Knapsack($capacity : capacity)
    $weightTotal : Number(intValue > $capacity) from accumulate(
    Item(
            $weight : weight),
        sum($weight)
        )
    then
    scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, $capacity - $weightTotal.intValue())
end`

Comment: Are we supposed to answer "yes" or "no"?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming `Item` is your planning entity and that it has a planning variable `boolean used`, then you 'll want to only check the items that are `used == true`:

```
    ... from accumulate(
        Item(used == true,
            $weight : weight),
        sum($weight)
    )
```